# Add FireBase analytics to Eclipse project

Tags: android, eclipse, firebase, firebase-analytics

I want to add my Eclipse project Firebase analytics, I did some research on this website, so I extracted the jar file from `firebase-analytics-9.4.0`, I placed it in libs folder, and I added it in build path, but still have to figure out how to added properly the JSON file, and what should I add/change in manifest file, taking in consideration that I added google play service library to the project.

For many reasons, I can't work with Android Studio (for now).

Thank you for you help!!

---

Answer (score 2):

The new Firebase (9xx) libraries can be found in the Google Repository. You can install this with the Eclipse Android SDK Manager. Open the SDK manager and scroll down until you find Google Repository and install the package.

The package will be installed in `/extras/google/m2repository` and you will find the Firebase files further down at `/com/google/android/firebase`.

You can rename the **.aar** files to **.zip** and extract the **jar** file, put this in a libs folder and then follow the instructions to import a project into Eclipse.

EDIT:

> The Android team has moved away from Eclipse and onto Android Studio .. this transition has taken more than a year. You will continue to face ever increasing problems by staying on Eclipse (this issue with Firebase is one of them).

Anyway you have to migrate soon. In the meantime.

Comment: yes i did all of that, but still how i can add the json files with the ID of my firebase accout?

Comment: Perhaps recompilation JSON files in the JAR will help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using Android studio. You can download a sample project from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/samples/) if you want to try.

Read the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup).  They have mention how to set it up in non android studio IDEs.

Comment: can you show me please where they mention how to set up in non android studio ide?

Comment: Check at the starting of the document.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this repository:
https://github.com/dandar3/android-google-firebase-README

There is a video at the end showing how to easily download the entire set of libraries (requires Subversive plugin, see the video above it).

Also keep an eye on this repository for Firebase Analytics:
https://github.com/dandar3/android-google-firebase-analytics

**UPDATE:**

Read all you need here:
http://dandar3.blogspot.com/2016/11/eclipse-integrate-firebase-analytics.html

In short, it's all about:

- following the `Processing the JSON file` section in the Google Services Gradle plugin documentation to bring the google-services.json configuration into your project - see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/gradle/#processing_the_json_file
- updating AndroidManifest.xml to add all the permissions, receivers, service etc that the Gradle plugin would generate for you in Android Studio (`app\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml`).